# Get SQL table names from create table statements using preg_match

Tags: php, sql, regex

I'm really bad with regex but I'm desperately trying to extract table names from SQL "create table" statements, I have something like this:

db.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);
```

There could be multiple create table statements, I want to get all table names for each of these, I tried using this regex:

```
<?php

$sql = file_get_contents('db.sql');
preg_match('/create\s+table\s+\`?\w+`/i', $sql, $tables);
var_dump($tables);
```

It sort of works:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "CREATE TABLE `ps_advbisn_subscription`"
]
```

However I want the return the match without the "create table" part, I read about look aheads and behinds and tried this:

```
<?php

$sql = file_get_contents('db.sql');
preg_match('/(?<=create\s+table\s+\`?)(\w+)(?=`?)/i', $sql, $tables);
var_dump($tables);
```

But all I get is `null`. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to catch a table name, it is done with `()`:

```
preg_match('/create\s+table\s+\`?(\w+)`/i', $sql, $tables);
var_dump($tables[1])
```

Comment: but why are there 2 results ?

Comment: Because first item is a __full__ string that matches regexp, second is a substring that you mark with `()` to be caught. If you add more `()` in your regexp - you will get more results.